# In Object Detection, do you train the CNN classifier on the Ground Truth bounding boxes?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, conv-neural-network

Let's take R-CNN, for example.  I know that there is the region proposal network and then a separate classification network, with the general idea being that it finds potential regions that could be an object, and then passes those regions to the classifier to figure out what it is.  I'm wondering how that classifier gets trained if I have a custom dataset.  Does it simply extract all the bounding boxes, create new images with those bounding box coordinates, preprocess them, and then use them for training?

In other words, are the classifiers used in object detection models trained on images generated based on the bounding box coordinates or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i understood from your question : "you want to understand how a classifier network works ?"

Well when we design a detector network followed by a classifier network, both the networks are trained on different kinds on training datasets. For example you want to detect different classes of vehicles like truck, bus, van, car, bike e.t.c.

1. Detector Network: This network will be trained using images that have marked bounding boxes around the vehicles in the scene. i.e coordinates of the bounding boxes. during testing this part of network, you will get results that will give you bounding boxes(coordinates) around the vehicles.
2. Classifier network: will be trained using cropped vehicle images with different class labels all resized to same dimensions for e.g. truck 1, bus 2, van 3, car 4 and so on.

Hence, while testing the whole pipeline(detector + classifier) after the detector network you will get multiple bounding boxes based on number of vehicles present in the scene. After that you need to resize all those cropped bounding box images to same dimension and feed one by one to classifier network. for e.g. a scene might have 5 vehicles then classifier will receive 5 vehicle images separately. You also need to retain the coordinates for the feeded cropped image to mark the class and location of vehicle on the result.

Comment: So I guess my follow up question would be: Is the classifier network trained on the original cropped bounding boxes (all the ground truth boxes) or is it only tagged on the bounding boxes that the detector network is able to logic?  For example, if we have an image with truck 1, bus 2, van 3, and the detector network only identifies the truck and the bus, is the van still cropped, resized, and fed into the classifier for training?

Comment: Depends on the use case output you desire. If you want to detect all the classes truck 1, bus 2 and van 3 then you have to train the classifier with all the separate classes cropped images i.e all 3 classes irrespective of the detector output. if detector output detects only 2 classes truck 1 and bus 2 then detector needs more fine tuning. But the classifier network needs to be trained on cropped images of all the classes you require.